# iPhone: UISearchBar how to search for "" String?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uisearchbar

I want to be able to search for a String without any character in it. The problem is, that the default keyboard does not show up the search button, when there is nothing written in the UISearchBar.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Markus

Comment: Why do you want to search for nothing?

Comment: because a empty search string returns everything... the search is like a filter...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Luckily, I just happened to be working on code that does exactly this.  It's a bit of a hack, but you can find the UITextField that is embedded within the UISearchBar, then turn off `enablesReturnKeyAutomatically`:

```
UITextField *searchBarTextField = nil;
for (UIView *subview in searchBar.subviews)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
    {
        searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)subview;
        break;
    }
}
searchBarTextField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = NO;
```

Comment: I like this answer too, but I don't think it's intuitive from a user experience point of view.

Comment: i used this for a completely other purpose: to pop up the keyboard by default when first showing a view with a UISearchBar, by calling [searchBarTextField becomeFirstResponder].  A real mystery why they didn't overload becomeFirstResponder for UISearchBar to do the right thing and show the keyboard.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Daniels answer works perfect till *iOS 7*.

**iOS 7 Update**

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *) bar
{
    UITextField *searchBarTextField = nil;

    NSArray *views = ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 7.0f) ? bar.subviews : [[bar.subviews objectAtIndex:0] subviews];

    for (UIView *subview in views)
    {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
            searchBarTextField = (UITextField *)subview;
            break;
        }
    }
    searchBarTextField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Type * and use that as a placeholder in your program for "" (nothing).

Answer (score 0):

Searching for `""` is like searching for nil / NULL:  the query will return all entries that are empty or null.

The `*` is a **wildcard** character used in most searching markups, and it'll return *all matches*.

Comment: Just to clarify further, `""` is **not** nil / NULL, but it's considered the *null string* (empty string).

Comment: Normally as more characters are added the filtered set reduces in count. Consequently if all search characters are removed, then what should "naturally" happen is that the entire unfiltered set is returned. ie. search for nothing is intuitively more closely aligned with an absence of filter.

Answer (score 0):

while searching a text. it is difficult to search a string without character...
so you need to work on

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    //write code here
}
```

it will run automatically

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did

To remove keyboard upon backspace till blank:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if ([searchText isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

you will also need to set your uitextfield within your uisearchbar to the same delegate , remember to add  to this delegate (in my code's context the delegate is self)

```
for (UIView *view in searchBar.subviews){
        if ([view isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]) {
            UITextField *tf = (UITextField *)view;
            tf.delegate = self;
            break;
        }
    }
```

following that add these to your delegate

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) aSearchBar {
    [aSearchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(searchBarCancelButtonClicked:) withObject:textField.superview afterDelay: 0.1];
    return YES;
}
```

when any of these trigger , perform your search for "" string